# Next.js ISR pass additional data to getStaticProps from getStaticPaths

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

In **SingleBlogPost.jsx** i have:

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:1337/api/posts");
  let { data } = await res.json();

  const paths = data.map((data) => ({
    params: { slug: data.attributes.slug },
  }));

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: "blocking",
  };
}
```

where I generate blog pages by their slug.
But then in getStaticProps I need to fetch single post by slug but I want to do it by id.

```
export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  console.log("context", context);

  const { slug } = context.params;

  console.log("slug is:", slug);
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:1337/api/posts");
  const { data } = await res.json();

  return {
    props: {
      data,
    },

    revalidate: 10, // In seconds
  };
}
```

And I want to keep url like /blog/:slug  , I dont want to include id. in url .When I already fetch all posts in  getStaticPaths how I can access post id in getStaticProps to avoid fetching by slug?

Comment: Take a look at this thread, some useful answers are posted [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/11272)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter your API response by your slug to get the same result

```
const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:1337/api/posts?filters[slug][$eq]${slug}`);
```

This will generate your desired result

Answer (score 1):

It looks like recently released a workaround using a file system cache.

The crux of the solution is that they save the body object in memory, using something like this:

`this.cache = Object.create(null)`

and creating methods to update and fetch data from the cache.

Discussion here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/11272#discussioncomment-2257876

Example code:
https://github.com/vercel/examples/blob/main/build-output-api/serverless-functions/.vercel/output/functions/index.func/node_modules/y18n/index.js#L139:10

Answer (score 0):

I found a concise work around that uses the `object-hash` package. I basically create a hash of the params object and use that to create the tmp filename both on set and get. The tmp file contains a json with the data I want to pass between the two infamous static callbacks.

The gist of it:

```js
function setParamsData({params, data}) {
  const hash = objectHash(params)
  const tmpFile = `/tmp/${hash}.json`

  fs.writeFileSync(tmpFile, JSON.stringify(data))
}

function getParamsData (context) {
  const hash = objectHash(context.params)
  const tmpFile = `/tmp/${hash}.json`

  context.data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(tmpFile))

  return context
}
```

We can then use these helpers in the `getStaticPaths` and `getStaticProps` callbacks to pass data between them.

```js
export function getStaticPaths(context) {
  setParamsData({...context, data: {some: 'extra data'})

  return {
    paths: [],
    fallback: false,
  }
}

export function getStaticProps(context) {
  context = getParamsData(context)

  context.data // => {some: 'extra data'}
}
```

I'm sure someone can think of a nicer API then re-assigning a argument variable.

The tmp file creation is likely not OS independent enough and could use some improvement.

Comment: It's nicer to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch-cache if you are fetching data over HTTP.