# Can't access multiple parameters of getStaticPaths from getStaticProps , Nextjs/Apollo/Graphql

Tags: javascript, graphql, next.js

Below you can check the code. I'm trying to use Id to identify single content and use titles for links,

> when I console log params.title
>
> > console: android-paging-advanced-codelab

but

> when I try to console log params.id,
>
> > console: undefined

I need to access both params inside the getStaticProps so I can use the exact data I need.

I did try context by passing context and using context.params.id but the result is the same.

read the code below and help me, please!

Here you can see the code of my getStaticPaths :

```
export async function getStaticPaths(){

  const { data } = await client.query({
    query: gql`
    query {
      postContents{
        data{
          attributes{
              post_card{
                data{
                  id
                  attributes{
                    TitleForLink
                  }
                }
              }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    `
  })
  
  const paths = data.postContents.data.map((item)=> {
    return {
      params: { 
        id: item.attributes.post_card.data.id.toString(), 
        title: item.attributes.post_card.data.attributes.TitleForLink.toString(), 
      }
    }
  })

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false,
  }

}
```

And the code of getStaticProps:

```
export async function getStaticProps({params}){
 
  const { data } = await client.query({
    query: gql`
    query {
      postCards{
        data{
          id
          attributes{
            post_content{
              data{
                id
                attributes{
                  Title
                  Description
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    `
  })
  console.log(params.id)
  return {
    props: {
      content: data.postCards.data,
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: When console logging paths object inside getstaticpaths, I get result I need, but in getstaticprops It gives me only one.

Comment: Is your dynamic route named `[title].js`? If so, only `params.title` will be available inside `getStaticProps`. You can't pass additional values from `getStaticPaths` to  `getStaticProps` (without your own custom logic), only what's defined in your folder structure.

Comment: yes, it is named [title].js.  can you show me an example of how to use any custom logic to achieve this, a tutorial, blog, or something?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You may find these useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70815626/next-js-isr-pass-additional-data-to-getstaticprops-from-getstaticpaths and https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/11272.

Comment: I want to use titles for links and IDs to identify single content from the query, they are 2 different properties and I need to get a matching Id to get the right content for a page, but can't find a way to export ID data from getstaticpaths. I could use IDs instead of titles for links but I want links to include words from title.

Comment: I saw those early but both are using IDs and I could do that, just wanted links to look like http://example.com/react-hooks not like http://example.com/1

Comment: I understand what you're trying to achieve, but again you can only pass one parameter if you're using a dynamic pages like `[title].js`. The idea behind those solutions I linked is to cache the data you retrieve in `getStaticPaths`, and access it inside `getStaticProps` so you have access to more than just the `title` that you passed through.

Answer (score 0):

The getStaticPaths function should return an object with paths parameters that determines which paths will be pre-rendered **only**, you can pass additional properties like *locale* if you have i18 configured.

So you need to make another fetching in the getStaticProps function.